# Laravel 5.4 - How to setup a optional parameter in a route. If it exists must be the word "home"?

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I have the follow code from Laravel routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{account}'], function (){

    Route::group(['prefix'=>'{location}'], function (){

        Route::get('/{home?}', function ($account,$location) { 
            $loc=explode("_", $location);
            $locale = $loc[0];
            $country= $loc[1]; 
            App::setLocale($locale);
            return view('homeProfPublic')->with(['account' => $account,'active' => 'home','locale'=>$locale,"country"=>$country]);  
        })->where('home', '/home/');
   });
});
```

I want this route to catch:

1. mysite.com/bob/US_en
2. mysite.com/bob/US_en/
3. mysite.com/bob/US_en/home

In other words I want the word "home" to be optional, but if it is there, to be only the word "home". All previuos route should redirect to the home page.

1. mysite.com/bob/US_en/contact  //Should redirect to contact page.

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do this in the route itself.

Check out how packages like [laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) handle this, by creating and applying route middleware which handle your localization.
The middleware will handle setting the locale, and you can create a service to return the account based on the first part of the url for example. This eliminates the need of having this logic in your routes at all.

What you have right now, is that you use the value of the optional home parameter, where you actually just want to define 2 routes (`/` and `/home`) to give the same output.

For the routes, I would suggest creating a controller action to handle displaying the view, and set up your routes to call the controller action instead of having this logic in your routes file. This takes away the need for duplicate code.

For example (using the localization package)

```
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]
],
function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@index');

    // add catchall as the last route in the group
    Route::get('{any}', 'HomeController@index')->where('any', '.*');
});
```

This will allow `/contact` to show the contact page, and everything else will give the output of the `HomeController@index` controller action.

To be honest, I would rethink the re-directing to home instead of showing a 404 on a non-existing url. If something doesn't exist, it doesn't exist :)

```
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]
],
function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@index');
});
```